# Ember data fetch json file

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I'm trying to get data from json file from server. My code:

**adapters/application.js:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://exampleweb.com',
    namespace: 'file.json'
});
```

**models/item.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('item');
    }
});
```

templates/application.hbs

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
{{item.name}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

JSON file on server look like this:

```
{
  "Products": [
  {
    "name": "Aviator"
  },
  {
    "name": "Dark"
  }]
}
```

Now ember requst http://exampleweb.com/file.json/items. How can I get this Products correctly and display them in template?

Comment: try `DS.RESTAdapter.extend` instead of `DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend` o r you need to change JSON response to JSON format

Comment: DS.RESTAdapter.extend gives same result

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, you have two options.

1. If you need to substitute backend for app development, the best choice is using ember-cli-mirage
2. If you need to get and display file's contents, you may not use ember data and do smth like

   ```
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     Ember.$.get('/path/to/file.json').then(resolve, reject);
   });
   ```

   in model hook